# BotFramework v4 Running Multiple Bots

Tags: botframework

I need to build a single Chatbot instance using BotFramework v4 that can handle multiple endpoints, and thus multiple AppID/Secret. I have seen notes online and in BotFramework samples that it is possible to do but I cannot find any specific examples for BotFramework v4.

1. Can anyone provide a sample on who to handle such scenario. For example, I would need to have endpoints /messages/hr and /messages/payroll, and depending on which endpoint is used the right AppID/Secret is used and specific MainMenuHrDialog or MainMenuPayrollDialog is launched.
2. In general, is it recommended to handle bots for different domains in the same bot project, or is it better to have separate projects for different domains with a NuGet package shared for common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, your desire to use different appIDs and secrets is gonna require multiple web app instances of similar botframework template code which executes different functions using an extension to their already existing api/messages endpoint(the default chatbot messaging endpoint). I'd recommend setting up a couple of azure web app instances along with a couple of bot channels registrations for connecting channels to your bot logic. Here's a decent resource for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-deploy-basic-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Though this doesn't apply directly to your scenario, you might want to check out this sample repo here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages. It shows you how you could open up those extra endpoints of /api/messages/hr or /api/messages/payroll. Additionally, I'm not sure how necessary the extra appIDs and secrets are for you but if your requirement is to ensure authorization when accessing these endpoints, I'd recommend looking into this prebuilt sample as well: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication. It possesses some info about authentication and how you might differentiate between users using a combination of conversation.activity.id and tokenResponses from AzureAD.